# Printer "ripping" forever (network printer)

Tags: printing, pdf

Since I installed Ubuntu 11.10, printing is a disaster. I did not have the problem with Lucid Lynx (Ubuntu 10.04), but maybe it just comes from the fact that someone else had installed it for me, and possibly it configured better.

When I print a pdf, even 2 pages, my printer (SHARP MX 2300N) stays in **rippen** for hours. "Rippen" is a German word, not really sure how to translate. Google translate says, The English equivalent is ["Rib"](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|rippen%0A). And eventually, sometimes, the pages finally get printed. But in between my whole floor is very angry because they also need the printer. Additionally, I don't always have the whole day for waiting for my pages.

I remember that when printing I used to be asked if I wanted to reduce transparency effects, which does not seem to happen anymore after I installed Ubuntu 11.10. Is there any connection? Not sure, because I don't think it was for pdf files.

Comment: PS: my "print status" icon is back when restarting... Still wonder why it disappeared...

Comment: Could you please separate your issues into separate questions?

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, well actually I will rather delete one of the pbs because I never had it again.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found the trick... Just replaced my Footmatic/pxlcolor driver by the equivalent Footmatic/Postscript.. I thought about it, although I have no idea who are those "pxlcolor" and "postscript" guys, because the other printer of my network is using a postscript driver and working perfectly well.

Wait, I just send a final test: Printing my whole thesis! or let's say 20 pages of it (I don't want to use all the paper of my company for a test :p)... Annnnd WORKING!!!! 3 months that I'm waiting for being able to do this halleluiah!

Comment: foomatic/postscript and foomatic/pxlcolor are just driver names. The first is the default postscript driver, the other an old PCL one.